# Select count & sum from order table, as well as count & sum from event table where order_id matches & event = expiry

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, one containing Order information and one containing Order Event information, example structure below:

**Orders Table:**

| merchant_id | order_id | amount | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 123456 | 100 | 2021-07-01 |
| 111111 | 789012 | 50 | 2021-07-20 |
| 111111 | 642443 | 75 | 2021-08-12 |

**Events Table:**

| merchant_id | order_id | event | amount | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 789012 | EXPIRY | 50 | 2021-08-03 |
| 111111 | 642443 | EXPIRY | 75 | 2021-08-28 |

**Desired Output:**

I am trying to get a breakdown by Merchant Id and month of:

- Order Count
- Order Sum
- Expiry Count *(how many of the orders placed in that month have expired regardless of date expired)*
- Expiry Sum *(value of the expiry count above)*

**Example Output:**

| merchant_id | order_month | order_count | order_sum | expiry_count | expiry_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111111 | 7 | 3 | 150 | 1 | 50 |
| 111111 | 8 | 1 | 75 | 1 | 50 |

I have tried a few queries with no luck, the furthest I've gotten is:

```
select o.merchant_id, extract(month from o.order_date) as order_month, count(o.order_id) as order_count, sum(o.order_amount) as order_sum, count(e.order_id) as expiry_count, sum(e.amount) as expiry_sum
from orders o
left join events e on e.order_id = o.order_id
where o.merchant_id = '111111'
and o.order_date >= '2021-07-01'
group by o.merchant_id, order_month
order by o.merchant_id, order_month
```

However that outputs the exact same values for order_count & expiry_count, as well as order_sum & expiry_sum. Additionally I need to only retrieve events where `event = 'EXPIRY'` however I get no results when I add that filter.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the condition on `event` to the *join* (not the where):

```
select o.merchant_id, extract(month from o.order_date) as order_month, count(o.order_id) as order_count, sum(o.order_amount) as order_sum, count(e.order_id) as expiry_count, sum(e.amount) as expiry_sum
from orders o
left join events e on e.order_id = o.order_id
    and e.event = 'EXPIRY'
where o.merchant_id = '111111'
and o.order_date >= '2021-07-01'
group by o.merchant_id, order_month
order by o.merchant_id, order_month
```

If you put a condition on an outer joined table in the *where* clause, you force the join to behave as an *inner* join (as if you deleted the `left` keyword).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much @Bohemian!